# the setWidth and setHeight method is invalid to change the button bigger or smaller in android RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

The xml is :

```
`<Button 
android:id="@+id/rxdButton"
android:layout_width="20dp"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@iddButton"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="R"
android:textSize="5dp"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:enabled="false"/>`
```

which is in the RelativeLayout.
And I try to change the size of the button, but I am failed.
So what is the problem?
Any answers would be very appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any code to show us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing something like this:

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.your_button);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = button.getLayoutParams();
params.height = yourHeight;
params.width = yourWidth;
button.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@iddButton"
```

rxdButton will appear at the end of width of @iddButton. 
If screensize is 100 and @iddButton width is 80, rxdButton width will get 20.
So rxdButton width can't be expand more than that